# Ajax request sometimes takes long time in tomcat

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have one ajax request which fetches data from java controller, generally the time taken by the request is 3-4 sec.
Sometimes it takes too long to retrieve data from it and results into client timeout exception which I think is because of ajax request timeout of 30 sec.
 After **restarting** tomcat it works properly and takes less time to serve request. This I am facing on my production server and not on localhost.

How to fix this ?

Exception is as follows-

```
DEV: 11:37:54.333 [http-443-18] /ssp/api/1/studentexternalmap/byStudentId ERROR o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Failed to invoke @ExceptionHandler method: public org.jasig.ssp.transferobject.ServiceResponse org.jasig.ssp.web.api.AbstractBaseController.handle(java.lang.Exception)
org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: null
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:369) ~[catalina.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:448) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:363) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:392) ~[catalina.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:381) ~[catalina.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:89) ~[catalina.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.write(SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper.java:435) ~[spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8Generator._flushBuffer(Utf8Generator.java:1754) ~[jackson-core-asl-1.9.4.jar:1.9.4]
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8Generator.flush(Utf8Generator.java:1088) ~[jackson-core-asl-1.9.4.jar:1.9.4]
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:1615) ~[jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.4.jar:1.9.4]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:203) ~[spring-web-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:179) ~[spring-web-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:148) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:90) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:189) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:69) ~[spring-web-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:122) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveHandlerMethodException(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:321) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.doResolveException(AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.java:60) [spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:136) [spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1148) [spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:985) [spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939) [spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856) [spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953) [spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844) [spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829) [spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290) [catalina.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:164) [urlrewritefilter-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:141) [urlrewritefilter-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:90) [urlrewritefilter-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:417) [urlrewritefilter-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) [catalina.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.jasig.ssp.security.uportal.KeepSessionAliveFilter.doFilter(KeepSessionAliveFilter.java:116) [KeepSessionAliveFilter.class:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343) [spring-web-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260) [spring-web-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) [catalina.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.jasig.ssp.security.uportal.UPortalPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(UPortalPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:98) [UPortalPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:131) [spring-security-oauth2-1.0.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343) [spring-web-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260) [spring-web-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) [catalina.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.jasig.ssp.security.uportal.RequestAndResponseAccessFilter.doFilter(RequestAndResponseAccessFilter.java:61) [RequestAndResponseAccessFilter.class:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343) [spring-web-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260) [spring-web-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) [catalina.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.jasig.ssp.security.RequestCleanupServletFilter.doFilter(RequestCleanupServletFilter.java:40) [RequestCleanupServletFilter.class:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343) [spring-web-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260) [spring-web-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) [catalina.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:151) [spring-orm-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) [catalina.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) [spring-web-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) [catalina.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:6.0.44]
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.helpers.MDCInsertingServletFilter.doFilter(MDCInsertingServletFilter.java:51) [logback-classic-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) [catalina.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233) [catalina.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191) [catalina.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:563) [catalina.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127) [catalina.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) [catalina.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [catalina.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293) [catalina.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861) [tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:620) [tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489) [tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.44]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_80]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkEOF(SSLSocketImpl.java:1496) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkWrite(SSLSocketImpl.java:1508) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:70) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(InternalOutputBuffer.java:761) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:448) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:363) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer$OutputStreamOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:785) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:124) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:598) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:533) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:364) ~[catalina.jar:6.0.44]
    ... 97 common frames omitted
```

Comment: How you managed to overcome this problem? I am also stuck in such kind of problem.